# What was the significance of not looking back in Pet Sematary?

Tags: stephen-king, pet-sematary

When the main character (Louis Creed) and the old man (Jud Crandall) go to the Indian burial ground, Jud tells Louis to not look behind while they are en route. I'm guessing this could have some allegorical value, to cast doubt aside and to admit that the deed they are about to commit is morally wrong and unnatural. But the warning was against physically looking back, which the character of Louis does in the movie (I haven't read the book. Did he also look behind in the book?)

So, what did that mean? Did it have any effect? Or was it a morsel of superstition in an otherwise "real" supernatural setting?

Comment: Perhaps it was a reference to the story of Orpheus and Eurydice, where when rescuing Eurydice from Hades if he looks back at her before they both leave the underworld she would vanish forever.

Comment: It's been a while since a read it, but wasn't the warning about the Wendigo (if you see the Wendigo, you develop a hunger for human flesh)? Probably not, since you'd have to walk with your eyes closed, just in case :P

Comment: Also the story of Lot's wife in the Bible. Seems to be embedded in the mythopoetic unconscious...

Comment: I agree with the Orpheus interpretation, especially as they're leaving a place of the dead. Though I don't know the story in question so I can't comment on further similarities.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if the instruction to not look back is while they're going to the place or leaving it...

Comment: @AndresF. As far as my girlfriend tells me, eating human flesh is what makes a Wendigo, but it's not "transmissible" by sight. Unless there's a variety she hasn't heard of.

Comment: @MPelletier I remember in Pet Sematary you become a cannibal just by seeing a Wendigo. But I don't have the book with me to confirm it...

Comment: @AndresF. OK. Sorry.

Comment: @MPelletier No need to be sorry :) I wasn't correcting you! I'm not sure either, or I would have provided a quote :)

Comment: In all cases "looking back" is a metaphor for regret or doubt. If you see a warning in literature against "looking back", you can bet that there is some lesson about doubt, trust, or regret. The reason is likely allegorical.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I got that part down already. I'm just wondering if there's something *more* besides the allegory.

Answer (score 2):

Any time you traverse through the underworld it is general advice that comes from the tale of Orpheus and Eurydice.  But the idea of not looking back to supernatural events or places is a recurring trope in Judeo-Christian, Fae, and Japanese myths just off the top of my head.